# EditText gets wider when a background color is set

Tags: android

I set a yellow background color for an EditText :

```
...
<EditText 
    android:id="@+id/identification"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:maxLength="25"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/marginRightScreen"
    style="@style/required" // here I set the background color
    >
        <requestFocus />
</EditText> ...
```

XML of the style :

```
<style name="required">
    <item name="android:background">@color/required</item> // #FF9
</style>
```

The problem is that at runtime the EditText's width is larger like if it is selected with the orange border :

[image]

So how to make its width the same as the other EditText's width ?

Comment: it is because of the padding, add some padding to your style attribute then it will be as you need.

Comment: No ! the width is still bigger !

Comment: What if you set the parent of your style to EditText? (something like this: `<style name="required" Parent="@android:style/Widget.EditText">`. You may be overriding the entire style for the edit text with a blank style which is ignoring all the default paddings, etc.

Comment: @kha , it does not work !

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
int width = mEditText.getWidth();

mEditText.setMaxWidth(width);
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to check the size of the EditText try using [uiautomatorviewer](http://developer.android.com/tools/testing/testing_ui.html) and check, if their sizes are different.

In your style you did not set values for margin and padding. Add a parent style to it, so it inherits the default values for layout attributes:

```
<style name="required" parent="@android:style/Widget.EditText">
    <item name="android:background">@color/required</item>
</style>
```

Comment: did you check the sizes?